# Use of SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO interface

Tags: android, superpowered

I create SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO for recording, and it starts working right away, which is fine. However, when I try to use the .onForeground() method when the android activity calls .onResume() it causes a crash... Even if I call onBackground() during onPause().

I also never call start()/stop(), and things seem to work find without calling any of these methods. I can't tell if it's draining battery, and why the methods fail or aren't seemingly needed.

http://superpowered.com/docs/_superpowered_android_audio_i_o_8h_source.html

How should I be using these appropriately?